# error-channel in http-inbound-gateway does not catch messaging exception occurs from message converter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundGateway"
                       path="inboundEndpoint"
                       supported-methods="PUT" request-payload-type="customJsonType"
                       message-converters="jacksonJSONConverter"
                       merge-with-default-converters="true"
                       error-channel="inboundErrorChannel"
                       request-channel="SendChannel"
                       reply-channel="ReplyChannel"/>

<int:channel id="SendChannel" />

<int:channel id="ReplyChannel" />

<int:channel id="inboundErrorChannel" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="inboundErrorChannel" ref="customErrorHandler" method="handle"/>

<bean id="customErrorHandler" class="CustomErrorHandler"/>
```

And here's handler.

```
public class CustomErrorHandler {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    public void handle(Message<?> message) {
    logger.debug("payload: {}", message.getPayload());
    }
}
```

when I send PUT curl command to /inboundEndpoint,
it returns error message like this,

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Could not convert request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for expected type
```

But SeerealErrorHandler catches nothing. (no log from CustomErrorHandler)

It seems spring default error handler manages return response to user.

How can I catch these error (from message converter) in error-channel?

- Problem is, exception from message converter is not catched, while other exception occured between SendChannel and ReplyChannel is catched. How can I catch exception from message converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion errors occur too early in the process; the error channel only gets errors that occur downstream of the gateway.

You could probably do something with a servlet filter.